# How to create ELF subsystem for BIN file in nasm?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

Welcome, how to create ELF subsystem for BIN file in nasm?
My bootloader is written in C.
My bootsector is written in NASM.

Comment: I've seen you ask a couple other related questions. You are going to have to write your own ELF loader from scratch or use code and ideas from something like [LIBELF](https://directory.fsf.org/wiki/Libelf) . OS Dev wiki has some basic info on parsing ELF headers: https://wiki.osdev.org/ELF_Tutorial

Comment: You still have to write the code to read ELF files from disk etc. That is more of a problem if you are in protected mode.

Comment: I previously asked if you were using GRUB. You said no, you are writing your own. I'm curious why you don't use GRUB as it does have basic elf executable support. Is there a reason why you need to write your own?

Comment: You could create an elf executable and the convert it to a binary file and load that directly into memory as a starting point.